# How can I access the default value for a keyword argument in Python?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm trying to use the `__defaults__` attribute of a function object to get default values for arguments. It works for this case:

```
>>> def test(x, y=1): pass
... 
>>> test.__defaults__
(1,)
```

but for this it doesn't:

```
>>> def test(*args, y=1): pass
... 
>>> test.__defaults__
>>>
```

Why does `test.__defaults__` contain `None`? How can I get the default value for the parameter in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You created a function with a *keyword-only* argument; you cannot use `y` as a positional argument. Keyword-argument defaults are stored in `__kwdefaults__`:

```
>>> test.__kwdefaults__
{'y': 1}
```

Quoting the Callable Types section of the [Standard Types hierarchy datamodel documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> `__kwdefaults__`: A dict containing defaults for keyword-only parameters.

You should really use the [`inspect` module `Signature` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object) to introspect callables however; it'll take care of details like these by providing you with a rich object instead:

```
>>> sig = inspect.signature(test)
>>> {name: param.default for name, param in sig.parameters.items()
...  if not param.default is param.empty}
{'y': 1}
```